# URL with multiple parameters as a query string in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, escaping, query-string, adfs

In ASP.NET, I build a string `redirectURL` to redirect to `ADFS` form with multiple query string parameters. One such complex parameter is the `returnURL` with multiple parameters.

My problem is that only the first parameter of the `returnURL` is available when it actually return.

```
E.g. redirectURL = <br> 
https://aaa.aaa/adfs/Form.aspx <br>
?DomainName=domain <br>
&AccountName=account <br>
&returnURL=https://bbb.bbb/MyPage.aspx?param1=111&param2=222
```

I know it complicates when identify the `&amp symbol` of actual parameters and parameters in `returnURL`. Please help me to fix this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you passing a page with params to a page with params? What kind of functionality are you trying to achieve?

Comment: To build the redirectURL there's a specific method and it builds only main three parameters (DomainName, AccountName, returnURL). Then after the function at Form.aspx it again redirect to returnURL. I want two parameters in that return url. It may sounds complicated, but I hope it isn't impossible.. Pls help

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should use **HttpUtility.UrlEncode** when composing the link and **HttpUtility.UrlDecode** when resolving it.

For your case it should be something similar to:

```
"https://aaa.aaa/adfs/Form.aspx?DomainName=domain&AccountName=account&returnURL=" + 
    HttpUtility.UrlEncode("https://bbb.bbb/MyPage.aspx?param1=111&param2=222")
```

And then at the target use:

```
HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["returnURL"])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Sorry it took sometimes for me to test this implementation.